# Не вносятся данные в БД. C#, WinForms

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, sql-server

Разбираюсь с подключением базы данных MS SQL Server к проекту c#. Работаю в Visual Studio Базу к проекту подключил с помощью опции "Подключение данных". Теперь пытаюсь добавить значение в базу, вроде всё правильно делаю, но в базу ничего не добавляется. Никаких ошибок не выводится. System.Data.SqlClient подключил.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=SLAVAPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Country_Colors;Integrated Security=True";
    string sqlExpression = "INSERT INTO (NameUK) VALUES ('test')";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlExpression, connection);
    }
}
```

Comment: А где `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: А куда его записать надо?:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не дописали код, вот так надо:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    var query = "INSERT INTO TableName (NameUK) VALUES ('test')";

    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Теперь при сборке возникает ошибка "Исключение не обработано. Неправильный синтаксис около конструкции `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`" ``

Comment: @Tom Ну да, укажите правильное имя таблицы в query:  `var query = "INSERT INTO TableName (NameUK) VALUES ('test')";`

Comment: А, дейтсвительно забыл. Теперь всё работает, спасибо.